# How to return jQuery Ajax data to a string

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to return jQuery Ajax data to a string?

code like this:

```
var data = $.get("e/as/ajax-dialog.php?do=member", function(data) {
    return data;
});
alert(data); == > [object]
```

`[object]` is not what I want

I want the ajax callback html code to **data[string]**..

### Update

My idea is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put result processing in the success handler

```
$.get("e/as/ajax-dialog.php?do=member", function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

In your example, `alert(data)` will be executed immediately after http request made and long before response is received.

More examples here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

**On question update.**
There's an example of synchronous request in [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
var html = $.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  async: false
}).responseText;
```

It's also explained there why making synchronous requests is generally bad idea. So, use it on your own risk.

Comment: var bodyContent = $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      type: "GET",
   }
).responseText;

I need the bodyContent to do something

I want to lik this

thanks Nikita Rybak

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is probably HTML code, just append it to some HTML node in your document and see, it could be jQuery's object wrapper around HTML.

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Also make sure the content-type of "e/as/ajax-dialog.php?do=member" is text/html,